Using Instagram API to fetch a public professional account posts without tokens from their side
I'm currently building a portfolio for a social media celebrity using Laravel 11 + vue3 composition API
I am at the point where I created a meta dev account and created an app and setup IG basic display API on it.
Now I am not sure if I can fetch that user's posts without obtaining any tokens or anything from their side.
Long story short:
Can I do something similar to this
Graph.instagram.com/[their_professional_account_id]/media?access_token=[my_app's token]
I don't want to ask them for any access tokens at all as they have 650k+ followers and I don't want to be involved in any access to their professional account.
I tried looking online for demos and examples but had no luck finding any and most articles are all about the deprecated __a?
